# How to extract text between HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to get differents data inside HTML tags on a distant webpages source code and put it under variables:

This is the part of the source code where i need data:

```
<h1>John Doe</h1> 
<p>Promotion: A.Sc. 2</p> 
<p>Campus de Paris</p>
```

And this is the result that I want on php:

```
$prenom='John' 
$nom='Doe' 
$promotion='A.Sc. 2' 
$campus='Paris'
```

For information I use it inside a Xamarin application for Android to get informations of a user by his id and send it to a database via php script. For the database part it's ok but I don't know anything about regex (I think web can do it with regex right ?)

Comment: provide more informaation to get answers, don't expect this question to be answer, it will be closed if it remains like this....
What kind of webpage you'll extract from??
What is your configuration?? (php, need js or not)
Where should the answer's code work??

Comment: I've added some details, hope it will be fine now

Comment: so much sorry to wast your time but, they have [Respect de la vie privée](https://www.supinfo.com/fr/respect_de_la_vie_privee.aspx), do this university allow you to use the data they have? I just can not be sure enough of the answer to help you (that's against the law if you're not allowed) but i can give you tips: first, this question is not for php or js, it's about Xamarin or android if you need... Look for ways to parse a webpage using Xamarin... Store the info you're supposed to get in a database if you should not get them automatically....

Comment: Yes they allow me, I'm a student from this university and I do it for the campus ;) For this time I juste get first name and last name with php but I do it really dirtily ^^

Comment: So sorry, still can't help too much, the easiest way for you is to go through the list and gather the info in a database and use it like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/)...................... if you have a facebook account we can break it more there

Comment: No problem ^^  This link is about local database but I do it with distant database and MySqli. I prefer to do it here to help future people with this problem ;)

Comment: you can make a generic question, think about law if people have laws that prevent them... if youve got access to the actual database i can answer then, but getting content from a page is just against the law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [The DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Example:

```
$html= "<p>hi</p>
<h1>H1 title</h1>
<h2>H2 title</h2>
<h3>H2 title</h3>";
 // a new dom object 
 $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
 // load the html into the object ***/ 
 $dom->loadHTML($html); 
 //discard white space 
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
 $hTwo= $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); // here u use your desired tag
 echo $hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 //will return "H2 title";
 ?>
```

Refer [DOM Parsing](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) too

Example:

```
// SimpleHtmlDom example
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/blah.php');

// Find all paragraphs 
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) 
       echo $element->innerText() . '<br>';
```